# ASP.Net core Connection string in Environment variables best practices for security

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables, connection-string

I am using Environment variables in ASP.NET  Core MVC app for my DB connection string.

I am connecting to DB with code below.

The connection is working correctly. I plan NOT to use connection string in appsettings for security reasons.
In Dev I use the launch settings file, in prod I will create env var in IIS

I would like to know is this correct practice please?

Thanks in advance

I have tried code below and all is working correctly.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_Connection"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only goal is to store the connection string securely, or not end up committing it into your repository, you should consider using user secrets in your dev environment.

Comment: Hi, I will be commiting to repos, this is why I want to leave security details our of appsettings.